# Why is Scala losing the actual type when it is assigned to an abstract type?

Tags: scala, abstract-type

Given the following code:

```
abstract class Foobar {

  type Parent <: Foobar

  def parent: Option[Parent]

}

class Foo extends Foobar {

  type Parent = Nothing

  val parent = None

  // ***
  // Taking the explicit declaration of the "bar" method's return type
  // "Bar" away convinces Scala to compile the code. In other words:
  //
  //      def bar() = new Bar
  // ***
  def bar(): Bar = new Bar {

    type Parent = Foo

    val parent = Some(Foo.this)

  }

}

abstract class Bar extends Foobar

(new Foo).bar().parent.get.bar()
```

My questions:

1. Can you explain why this is happening? See inline comment above.
2. Do you have a solution for this?

I'm getting the following error message from Scala-SDK's Scala Worksheet in version 3.0.2-vfinal-20131028-1923-Typesafe:

```
Multiple markers at this line
  - value bar is not a member of scrap.Bar#Parent
  - value bar is not a member of scrap.Bar#Parent
```

OK, leaving out the "bar" method's return type declaration leaves me with the following info message from the Scala Worksheet:

```
> res0: scrap.Bar{type Parent = scrap.Foo; val parent: Some[scrap.Foo]} = scra
                                                  //| p$Foo$$anon$1@3bba229e
```

Is there a way to give this type a decent name, ideally "Foobar#Parent"?

Comment: Please post the compiler error. I know it seems pedantic, but a future version of scalac might behave differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens in

```
(new Foo).bar().parent.get.bar()
```

is :

- `new Foo` is `Foo`
- `.bar()` in `Foo` is of type `Bar` (declared so, even if the actual result is more than that)
- `.parent` in `Bar` is not redefined, neither is Parent, so it is just `parent: Parent <: FooBar` inherited from FooBar. The bound `FooBar` will be used.
- there is no `bar` in FooBar, so `.parent.bar()` fails.

If you declare in Foo

```
def bar(): Bar { type Parent = Foo} = new Bar {// same as your code}
```

or simply

```
def bar() = new Bar {// same }
```

letting the type be inferred, it works fine.

If you declare `def bar(): Bar`, this is where the typing stops. Just as if you declare `def bar(): Any = whatever`, it will not consider the type of `whatever`. And a subtype of `Foo` would be allowed to return a `Bar` with a different `Parent` type.

---

Regarding your update : 
I 'm not sure why I would want to have that type displayed as  `FooBar#Parent`, which tells close to nothing, but anyway, I don't think you can persuade scala to do that.

The easy way to have a simple display would be to name the type you return there rather than  anonymously extend `Bar`. If you don't want to do that, you have at least to declare the return type of the method, which is good practice anyway. Otherwise, scala will display what it infers, with maximum precision. You can use `def Bar: Bar {type Parent = Foo} = ...`, or you may declare a type alias for that (preferably, outside Foo) :

```
type BarWithFooParent : Bar {type Parent = Foo }
def bar(): BarWithFooParent = new Bar() { … }
```

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation is of great help to me. I've got one more question. See above. Can you provide any insight?